# Is it possible to have both kahaDB and memoryPersistenceAdapter for different queues in Activemq?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.8 with the kahaDB persistenceAdapter but have a requirement to turn off kahaDB persistence for a single queue

I have been unable to find any documentation on how to disable persistence for a single queue.

The current config is

```
   <persistenceAdapter>
      <kahaPersistenceAdapter directory="activemq-data" maxDataFileLength="33554432"/>
   </persistenceAdapter>
```

Does anyone know how this can be achived?

I have tried to use a filteredPersistenceAdapters and use memoryPersistenceAdapter for the queue I want to disable kahdb one without success as it seems you can not use them both eg.

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <mKahaDB directory="kahadb">
         <filteredPersistenceAdapters>
              <filteredKahaDB>
                              <persistenceAdapter>
                                              <kahaDB"> </kahaDB>
                              </persistenceAdapter>
              </filteredKahaDB>
              <filteredKahaDB queue="queue-one">
                              <persistenceAdapter>
                                             <memoryPersistenceAdapter> </memoryPersistenceAdapter>
                              </persistenceAdapter>
              </filteredKahaDB>
         </filteredPersistenceAdapters>     
    </mKahaDB>                      
</persistenceAdapter>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support at the moment for mixing persistence adapter types in the way you are asking.  The mKahaDB adapter expects that all the filtered adapters are going to be of the KahaDB variety and so what you are trying won't work.  There's a fair bit of complexity in mixing persistence adapters especially in the area of transaction consistency and so this is not something that has been worked on.

The project accepts contributions so if it is something you really want to see implemented dive in and see if you can get it sorted.

Comment: thank you for the comment. Just to confirm there is no way to turn off persistence for a single queue?

Comment: Send the messages with persistent = false, otherwise no, the broker assumes that if you told it to use persistence that you meant it.